# VBA Excel. How to disable resizing and rotation of a textbox?

Tags: interop, excel, vba

I'm using the Excel interop and C# to create a worksheet with some form controls. I add a textbox to the sheet like this:

```
WorkSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal,
Convert.ToInt32(cell.Left),
Convert.ToInt32(cell.Top),
Convert.ToInt32(cell.Width),
Convert.ToInt32(cell.Height));
```

With that I add the control but then when I go to the resulting workbook and click on the textbox to change the text the options to move it and rotate it appear over it (dots on its corners and a green dot to rotate it)

Since I want the textbox on the cell I put it on I don't want the user to be able to rotate, move or resize it. How can I disable this? If I lock the control I can't change the text.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Unlock Text feature, but I've never been able to find a way to set it programmatically.